# Why is pandas creating NaN for resampling of sql data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to pandas and numpy and trying to aggregate measurement values to an equally spaced time series. The input data is not equally spaced and looks like:

```
timestamp            value  
2016-08-09 11:55:26  1779.510  
2016-08-09 11:55:26  1792.310  
2016-08-09 11:55:27  1796.900  
2016-08-09 11:55:28  1749.760 
2016-08-09 11:55:29  1780.870  
...                  ...
```

Now what I'm trying is reading the data from MySQL and then resampling it to an equally spaced time series.

```
query = "SELECT timestamp, value FROM iren2.data WHERE data.timestamp >= now() - INTERVAL {0} DAY " \
            "AND data_node_id = {1} ".format(1, 307)

data = pandas.read_sql_query(query, engine, parse_dates=True, index_col='timestamp')
aggregation = pandas.DataFrame()
aggregation['value'] = data.resample('1min').mean()
print(aggregation)
```

which prints:

```
[104301 rows x 1 columns]  
      value  
0       NaN  
1       NaN  
...     ...
```

That's not really what I expected :/

Thanks in advance!

**Update to EdChum's comment**

`data.info():`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 106661 entries, 2016-08-09 13:06:13 to 2016-08-10 13:06:13
Data columns (total 1 columns):
value    106661 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 1.6 MB
```

None

Comment: What is the `dtype` of value column? can you post the output from `data.info()`

Comment: what does `data.resample('1min').mean()` show? the problem here could be that you're assigning to an empty df with an incompatible index which is why your datetimeindex isn't copied across as initially the index is an `int64Index` for instance you could do `aggregation = pandas.DataFrame({'value':data.resample('1min').mean()})`

Comment: Yeah, you're totally right!! Thanks! It's the assignment to an empty df.
`print(data.resample('1min').mean()` works perfectly.

Comment: OK will post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you're trying to add a new column with data with an incompatible index, when you create an empty df the index type will be `object` dtype initially, you're adding data where the index is `datetimeIndex` so you get `NaN` for all rows.

If you pass the data and index in the `ctor` of the df then this will work:

```
In [9]:
resampled = df.resample('1min').mean()
empty_df = pd.DataFrame({'value':resampled}, index = resampled.index)
empty_df

Out[9]:
                       value
timestamp                   
2016-08-09 11:55:00  1779.87
```

If you want an int index then you can do:

```
In [17]:
resampled = df.resample('1min').mean()
empty_df = pd.DataFrame()
empty_df['value'] = pd.Series(resampled, index=np.arange(len(resampled.index)))
empty_df

Out[17]:
     value
0  1779.87
```